# How to pass image between fragments

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, bundle

i have a listView, there are checkbox, image, text. I need to check some of this listView rows and when i click next, i need to see the checked images in next fragment.

I tried here, but that not working. What's wrong?

I need to pass the data from `FragmentLanguage` to `PersonalInfoFragment`.

```
public class FragmentLanguage extends Fragment {

View mainView;
ListView listView;
Button clear, next;
PersonalInfoFragment info = new PersonalInfoFragment();

int[] images = {R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download};

String[] languages = {"Armenian", "Russian", "US English", "Portugal",
        "Spanish", "Georgian", "French", "Italian"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);

    listView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), languages, images);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    clear = mainView.findViewById(R.id.clear_lang);
    next = mainView.findViewById(R.id.next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                if (listView.isItemChecked(i)) {
                    bundle.putInt("Images", images[i]);
                    info.setArguments(bundle);

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                            new PersonalInfoFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return mainView;
}}
```

That was the the fragment where i have to check the elements and save the checked images.

And here's the class where i need to pass the saved images.

```
public class PersonalInfoFragment extends Fragment {

View mainView;

EditText skills_description;
Button clear, save, languages;

CircleImageView circleImageView1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_info, container, false);
    init(mainView);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        circleImageView1.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Images"));
    }

    return mainView;
}

private void init(View v) {
    skills_description = v.findViewById(R.id.skills);
    clear = v.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    languages = v.findViewById(R.id.select_language);
    save = v.findViewById(R.id.save);

    circleImageView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.language1);

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            skills_description.setText("");
        }
    });

    languages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    new FragmentLanguage()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: It should work, does this ever return true : `listView.isItemChecked(i)`? Put a `Log.d()` statement in it to check in Logcat.

Comment: Yeah i know, i saw, there's a checkbox problem

Comment: can you check two or more images, If yes than you are adding PersonalInfoFragment two or more time in for loop

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set setItemChecked for particular position

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(object :AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                list.setItemChecked(p2,true)
            }

        })
```

Now you can call `isItemChecked` for that position

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass different arrays(languages and images) to adapter. you will need **Domain/POJO Class**  which contains values and getter/setter method.

```
class StudentInfo {
    private String Name;
    private int Image;
    private boolean isSelected;


    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
    public StudentInfo(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
    public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(int Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    public StudentInfo(String name, int Image) {
        Name = name;

        this.Image = Image;
    }
}
```

Your solution is here.
Please have a look [Listview With Checkbox](http://appemed.blogspot.in/).

please ask if any confusion.

Comment: Ok man thanks, i'll try this later, now i have to go))) Today i'll try this, if something will not work, i'll ask you. But when i saved the image to the bundle, in my code, is there all right? And can I create another class for the adapter? because the MainActivity is very long))

Comment: listView.isItemChecked(i) will not work if you are working with check boxes.
you need to work with arrayList.